# How to serialize interface to JSON in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json

I try to filter out unnecessary properties by casting object to some interface. Next, I serialize it to JSON object like the following code.

```
@{ 
    var program = ViewBag.Program as IProgram;
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.program = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(program));
</script>
```

However, It still serialize all properties in original object instead of serialize only properties that are defined in interface.

How to serialize only properties in current object type instead of serialize all properties that are in original object?

Comment: Why does it matter?  Besides using memory you don't need, does it really matter you have extra properties?  As long as the properties for the Interface are included.

Answer (score 0):

Use a view model of course:

```
@{ 
    var program = new 
    { 
        Foo = ViewBag.Program.Property1,
        Bar = ViewBag.Program.Property2
    };
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.program = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(program));
</script>
```

and by the way this is something that should be done inside your controller action, not clutter your view. So instead of passing this object inside ViewBag.Program directly pass a view model that will contain only the properties you need to be serialized.

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    Program program = ...
    ViewBag.Program = new
    {
        Foo = ViewBag.Program.Property1,
        Bar = ViewBag.Program.Property2
    };
    return View();
}
```

Oh, and use a real view model and cut that ViewBag out.

Comment: I know this way. But it doesn't professional way to solve this problem.

Comment: @Soul_Master, well then I am leaving you to do it *professionally* as you wish. That's what I would do. I would repeat myself in this situation. Well actually I would use a real view model instead of using any ViewBag as I've mentioned in my answer. Feel free to ignore my answer if you consider it bad for your coding practices.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But I'm still looking for answer that use serializer to solve this problem.